# Probability theory: Convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I have been working on this problem for hours and I am not at all that convinced I have a correct solution.

$\textbf{Problem.}$ Let $\varepsilon, \delta>0$ and  let $\{X_{i}\}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of independent nonnegative random variables defined jointly on some probability space such that

$\mathbb{P}[X_{i}\geq \delta]\geq \varepsilon$
 for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that with probability one,
$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_{i}=\infty$.

$\textbf{Proposed solution}$ Since we are assuming having probability one, then
$1=\mathbb{P}[\cap_{i\geq 1}\cup_{k\geq i}X_{k}]$ is equivalent to $0=\mathbb{P}[\cup_{i\geq 1}\cap_{k\geq i}X_{k}^{c}]$, by subadditivity, $0=\mathbb{P}[\cap_{k \geq i}X_{k}^{c}]$. Here is where I don't know how to relate the hypothesis of $\delta,\varepsilon>0$. I only suppose each $X_{i}$ is independent as follows:

$0=\mathbb{P}[\cap_{k \geq i}X_{k}^{c}]\leq \mathbb{P}[\cap_{k=i}^{i+n}X_{k}^{c}]=\prod_{k=i}^{i+n}\mathbb{P}(X_{k}^{c})=\prod_{k=i}^{i+n}(1-\mathbb{P}[X_{k}])\leq \prod_{k=i}^{i+n}\exp\{-\mathbb{P}[X_{k}]\}=\exp\{-\sum_{k=i}^{i+n}\mathbb{P}[X_{k}]\}.$

So how may I use $\mathbb{P}[X_{i}\geq \delta]\geq \varepsilon$, maybe if I choose $i_{k+1}\geq i_{k}$ given $i_{k}$ so that $\mathbb{P}[X_{i_{k}}\geq \delta_{k}]\geq \varepsilon_{k}$, then apply sum... I am confused. Hints, partial solutions are greatly appreciated. Thanks very much in advenced.

Comment: *Hint.* 2nd Borel-Cantelli lemma tells that $\mathbb{P}[X_i \geq \delta \text{ i.o.}] = 1$.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you two hints:

1. The event comprising the set of points that the series converges is a tail event. Since you have a sequence of independent variables, each tail event has probability 0 or 1.
2. If a series (sequence of the partial sums) converges a.s. then it converges in probability. Now use the contra-positive of the argument.

I hope it helps.